# Most of time facing Access denied issue for Exchange server

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server, powershell-remoting, access-denied

I am trying to establish a PowerShell session to run several Exchange commands on an Exchange server on the localhost. This is not a constant issue, script is running successfully for sometime, but most of the time it is throwing following error:

```
New-PSSession : [Exchange-server-name] Connecting to remote server Exchange-server-name failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more 
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:9 char:15
+ $newsession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri ...
+
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed
Import-PSSession : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.
At line:10 char:27
+ import-PSSession -session $newsession -AllowClobber
```

Following is my PSSession command:

```
$newsession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://Exchange-server-name/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Credential
```

Comment: Ever found a solution to this? It also occurs randomly for us